# How to fix error in gradle that won't build app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

An error occurs during build:

**Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project 'Svetofor' of type org.gradle.api.Project.**

Code where the error occurs **build.gradle (Svetofor) :**

```
build.gradle(Project: AndroidStudioProjects)
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }




// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.properties:**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

Please help me to fix the error in order to build the application

Comment: Please paste what you have in **gradle.properties** file?

Comment: @Artem Please don't misuse comments for posting code (code in comments is totally unreadable). Please edit your question instead and deleted the comments.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip, I've added build.properties to the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `build.gradle(Project: AndroidStudioProjects)`